# Sanitising user input to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

An internal web application I have developed will be pen tested soon.  It uses Windows Authentication.

It has quite a lot of AJAX.  I was reading about cross site scripting recently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

The article talks about sanitizing user input.  Is there a function that will do this in JavaScript/Jquery?

For example, if the user enters: `<script type='text/javascript'>alert('xss');</script>`, then how can I sanitise this? To prevent SQL Injection attacks you use command parameters, which are built in to .NET.

I could replace the inappropriate tags myself, however I just wanted to make sure there was not a built in way of doing this first.  I have spent some time Googling, but I have not found an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Take a look at recommendations from OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always treat user input as text, not as HTML.

So say you want to show the users input in a div, you'd do:

```
$("#mydiv").text(userInput);
```

This will automatically 'sanitize' the input (it doesn't really, see below) , you'll see the input HTML as text rather than it being injected as HTML. Of course if you used .html() then it would just be dumped in as is.

What's actually happening is you're (or rather jquery is)  giving the browser an explicit instruction to treat something as text rather than HTML so it never tries to parse it in the first place, which is always the more secure option compared to trying to sanitise something it's going to parse.